# Apply exact stat parameters from one file to another using C in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions, stat

I would like get stat parameters from one file and later apply it as is, to a copy of the same file (Including type, path, permissions, size, etc.).
The original file will be long gone from this directory and the copy will take his place, and should get the same exact properties.
How could this be done using C in Linux?

Comment: this is hard to understand, can you elaborate?  You are trying to restore a file, but not the contents, just the location, size and permissions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Of all the properties you mention, only one (permissions) can be transferred from one file to another. The other ones (type, size) are intrinsic attributes of the file, and it would not make sense to set them without also changing the file's content.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I need to transfer between the files the time, permissions, and all the rest besides type, path and size. Is there a single command to do so?

Comment: Note that not all parameters of the new inode can be set to be like the old one. ctime/otime changes are not without go-around hassles (clock reset), and getting the same inode number is a game of luck.

Comment: I get your point. I will do this one parameter at a time: utime, lchown, chmod chown,etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need to write your own program to do that.

If your files reside on the same machine, you can preserve and restore times and permissions in [`tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) archives. The `p` option handles permissions, and times are persisted by default (except `atime`, but `--atime-preserve` can work around that).

Alternatively, if you want to restore files from a remote server, you can use [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) with the `-a` option.

Comment: I actually need to do something like what tar does, for archiving folder and files while retaining their properties (on the same machine). Good to learn on the resync, in this case it may be an overkill.